# how do the conjunctive forms work here?

Tags: grammar

The sentence in question:
少子化の影響などで婚姻件数そのものが減っているのに加え、結婚しても式や披露宴などを行わない、いわゆる「ナシ婚」が増えて、そのあおりでブライダルの市場規模が縮小傾向にあるのです。

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/business_tokushu/2018_0621.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_004

My attempt at translation:
"Even though the decling birthrates effect and the number of marriages itself shrinks, it increases and though people do marriage, they don't do ceremony and celebration and what is called "nankon" increases and with this **???gust (of wind)???** the wedding planning marketscale is in declining trend."

After I had googled  ナシ婚 　I could somehow figure out what this sentence is about, but obviously I'm still confused by the grammar. Especially 
少子化の影響などで婚姻件数そのものが減っているのに**加え** really throws me off. I can't find any explicitely articulated reference point for 加え in the sentence and I don't know what to extrapolate from the context. Then, it is directly followed by 結婚しても which I find hard to integrate in this grammatical context which already makes it hard for me to find out what is being said **precisely** here.^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「少子化{しょうしか}の影響{えいきょう}などで婚姻件数{こんいんけんすう}そのものが減{へ}っているの**に加{くわ}え**、結婚{けっこん}しても式{しき}や披露宴{ひろうえん}などを行{おこな}わない、いわゆる「ナシ婚{こん}」が増{ふ}えて、**そのあおり**でブライダルの市場規模{しじょうきぼ}が縮小傾向{しゅくしょうけいこう}にあるのです。」

Having answered nearly 2,000 questions, I will confidently state that users here tend to translate things too hastily -- namely, they translate even before they understand the sentence structure (and all the grammar and vocabulary used).  That is not going to work with longer sentences.

Stripped of all the verbiage, the core structure of this sentence is:

> 「In addition to (に加えて) **Cause A**, there is also **Cause B** and due to those factors (そのあおりで), **Effect X** is occuring. 」

Cause A: 少子化の影響などで婚姻件数そのものが減っている

Cause B: 結婚しても式や披露宴などを行わない、いわゆる「ナシ婚」が増えている

Effect X: ブライダルの市場規模が縮小傾向にある

If you have the above figured out, all that is left to do is to translate each component and put them together into a coherent English sentence.

Before that, my own TL for 「ナシ婚」 would be "***wedding-less marriages***" and 「あおり」 means a "***negative influence***".

My mostly-literal TL attempt of the whole sentence:

> "In addition to the fact that the number of marriages is (already) decreasing due to the declining birthrates, the number of the so-called 'wedding-less marriages' where the couples get officially married without going through any ceremonies is on the increase; therefore, as a consequence of both factors, the market size of the bridal industry is indeed shrinking.